# How to save different words in C# to .txt

Tags: c#

So I am a first year college student and I have a project to do - a simple hang man game.
This is my current code part for saving each word that needs to be guessed into a text file.
But if I use it, it always deletes the previous word, not list it up on a new line.

Can someone help me with this?

Sorry for my poor formatting and poor English. I'm German.

```
Console.WriteLine("The word what need to be guessed: ");            
            string kitalalszo = Console.ReadLine(); //saving the word           
            StreamWriter iras = new StreamWriter("test.txt"); //saving the first word into txt
            iras.WriteLine("{0}", kitalalszo); //writing down the word i put it in, on console, to a txt
            iras.Close();

            StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("test.txt", append: true); //next word in ..
            sr.WriteLine("\n{0}", kitalalszo); //saving the next word into a new line
            sr.Close();
//close
```

Comment: The filename is different in the second time (i.e., "teszt.txt"). Is that a typo?

Comment: You are already using `WriteLine`, so what is the point of the formatting?

Comment: Should be .write ?

Comment: @41686d6564 yeah it was a typo when i translated to english, but its the same in the original

Comment: @TaW i tried with .write its the same, it repeats the first word twice in the txt.

Comment: @Mattgwat Do you change `kitalalszo` before second write?

Comment: _its the same in the original_ Well only one is opening with append.

Comment: @TaW yeah that was it, I need to open with the " append ", and i need an if(File:Exists(test.txt)) for testing if that file is there

Comment: _i need an if(File:Exists(test.txt)) for testing if that file is there_ that depends. if it isn't there it will be created. Also: I would use writeline but without any formatting, unless it is needed..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple scenario then it is easier to use:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("path", "body");
System.IO.File.AppendAllText("path", "body");
```

You don't need to handle StreamWriter.